# c# XDocument Xsd pattern validation with character $

Tags: validation, xsd, design-patterns

I have a problem with c# XDocument XSD validation.

The following file is validated well by Xml Spy, but not by .Net (c#)

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Simple.xsd">
    <Var Name="$Toto"/>
</Root>
```

Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Var">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="ST_VariableIdentifier" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
        <xs:simpleType name="ST_VariableIdentifier">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="$[a-z,A-Z]*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

An idea?

Comment: Would this benefit from a C# tag?

Comment: This is a bug in the C#, for which there is a workaround: use [$]. Don't bother trying things such character references, e.g. &#x24; , for some reason C# is very picky here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Var">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="ST_VariableIdentifier" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="ST_VariableIdentifier">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[$][a-z,A-Z]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing answer. This is actually a known 'bug' in the .Net implementation of the W3C specs (acknowledged [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/390085/xsd-pattern-restriction-not-being-correctly-interpreted) on Connect, but *Won't fix*).

MSDN provides more information ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd322806%28VS.90%29.aspx)), together with the workaround mentioned above.

> The System.Xml implementation of the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)
>   Recommendations for XML Schemas uses the RegEx class to perform
>   pattern matching of regular expressions. In some cases, the behavior
>   recommended by W3C differs from the RegEx class behavior. The
>   following are the known cases where the System.Xml implementation of
>   pattern matching differs from the W3C specification:
>
> According to the W3C for XML Schema specification, the dollar sign ($)
>   should be treated as a regular character. However, the System.Xml
>   validation interprets a dollar sign in the xs:pattern as an
>   end-of-line anchor. The possible workaround is to replace $ with [$].
>   If your pattern is already in brackets, such as [abc$], it is not
>   necessary to make any changes.